# Most efficient way in adding identity column to a datatable with data in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable

```
Domain  Username 
x        joe1
y        sam1
```

What is the most efficient way in adding an identity column

Output:

```
Row Domain  Username 
 2   x        joe1
 3   y        sam1
```

I want the seed to start with 2.

This is my code currently, I populated a datatable with values from excel then add an identity column.  The problem is the Identity column is understandably empty when I do this.

```
reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file.InputStream);
reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
dtDetails = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[0];
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Row");
dc.AutoIncrement = true;
dc.AutoIncrementSeed = 2;
dc.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
dtDetails.Columns.Add(dc);
dc.SetOrdinal(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem but I am not quite sure if this is the most efficient way since the application will be dealing with hundreds to thousands of records.

this is how I did it.

```
DataTable dtIdentity = new DataTable();
reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file.InputStream);
reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
dtDetails = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[0];
DataColumn columnIdentity = new DataColumn("Row");
columnIdentity.AutoIncrement = true;
columnIdentity.AutoIncrementSeed = 2;
columnIdentity.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
dtIdentity.Columns.Add(columnIdentity);
dtIdentity.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("Domain"), new DataColumn("Username") });

foreach (DataRow dr in dtDetails.Rows) 
{
    dtIdentity.Rows.Add(null, dr[0], dr[1]);
}
```

I created a new datatable and added row rolumn(identity) and the others columns.  Then I loop through the datatable with the data and added each row.

A more efficient answer would be appreciated.